# How to use a global const variable defined on a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, porting

I have next file **common/const.h**:

```
#ifndef COMMON_CONST_H
#define COMMON_CONST_H

#if defined _WIN32 || defined _WIN64
#ifdef PCOM_EXPORTS
#define PCOM_WINAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PCOM_WINAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif // PCOM_EXPORTS
#endif // _WIN32

namespace common {

extern PCOM_WINAPI const char DIR_SEPARATOR;

}

#endif /* COMMON_CONST_H */
```

And **common/const.cpp**:

```
#include "common/const.h"

namespace common {

#if defined _WIN32 || defined _WIN64
const char DIR_SEPARATOR = '\\';
#else
const char DIR_SEPARATOR = '/';
#endif

}
```

I generate Its DLL file without problems. But when I want to use this **DIR_SEPARATOR** variable from another library I get:

> Util.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const
>   common::DIR_SEPARATOR" : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Util.cpp (dll client) code is:

```
#include "common/const.h"
...
namespace db {
...
shared_ptr<iptree> Util::loadIniFile(const string& filePath) {
  string file = filePath;
  replace(file.begin(), file.end(), '/', prompt::common::DIR_SEPARATOR);
  shared_ptr<iptree> tree(new iptree);
  ...
}

}
```

My questions are:

- Why I get ***unresolved external symbol "char const
  common::DIR_SEPARATOR"*** if I'm including common/const.h (`namespace common { extern PCOM_WINAPI const char DIR_SEPARATOR; }`) on Util.cpp?
- All these code is working perfectly on Linux (.so generated and used
  by a client). Why I get this errors porting it to Windows? Visual
  Studio 2017 uses C++14 as standard by default. On Linux I use C++11. Dll project and client project have same configurations. So I'm almost sure the problems is not here.
- What do I need to do to get working these code?

I would like set **DIR_SEPARATOR** value once only. Is it possible on this case? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use dependencywalker to find out whether the symbol is exported. BTW: Most coding guidelines reserve `ALL_UPPERCASE` for macros, just to make clear what it is.

Comment: are you include *lib* file to linker input ?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - what is inside *dll* exported at this stage not play any role. linker not look for dll at all. linker use *lib* file. need include this *lib* to build

Comment: @RbMm Yes, I am.

Comment: That's true, @RbMm. However, since the DLL and the according stubs are built together, they typically match and checking for exported symbols is a first step to diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @jplc - you trunctate linker error.must be something like *error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const common::DIR_SEPARATOR" (__imp_?DIR_SEPARATOR@common@@3DB)* - paste full error message and search for **exactly** this symbol name *__imp_?DIR_SEPARATOR@common@@3DB* in lib

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - no, need look not in *dll* but in *lib* file in this stage

Comment: why is `prompt::common::DIR_SEPARATOR` instead `common::DIR_SEPARATOR` ? i not view `__declspec(dllimport) ` in error message and linker also always show full decorated symbol name. are you exactly paste linker error ?!

Comment: You made it clear that your strategy is slightly different, @RbMm, but there is no right or wrong here. Both are quick checks to circle in on the cause of the error.

Comment: I just cut code (namespaces) to be more simple @RbMm

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt not agree. exist right here and exactly why i say. need look *lib* file if error on link step. need look *dll* file if error in runtime

Comment: @jplc - *I just cut code (namespaces) to be more simple* - never do this. paste **full and exactly** error message from linker

Comment: what is `prompt` namespace ? must be `common::DIR_SEPARATOR` instead `prompt::common::DIR_SEPARATOR`. and why not *error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const common::DIR_SEPARATOR" (__imp_?DIR_SEPARATOR@common@@3DB)* error message ? why not view *__declspec(dllimport)* ? look like you confuse symbols

Comment: in your lib file must be *__imp_?DIR_SEPARATOR@common@@3DB* - can use simply text search. and paste exactly error from linker

Comment: @RbMm Full namespace is prompt::common and the error is:
1>Util.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const prompt::common::DIR_SEPARATOR" (?DIR_SEPARATOR@common@prompt@@3DB)
1>C:\...\src\main\prompt\db\msvc\2017\Release\pdba.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "pdba.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: but what you want if in dll you use `common::DIR_SEPARATOR` only ? no any `prompt` namespace. of course will be error. in your lib must exist **`__imp_?DIR_SEPARATOR@common@@3DB`** symbol (search for it). but not exist of course `?DIR_SEPARATOR@common@prompt@@3DB`

Comment: so you not use symbol from "common/const.h" at all. you use absolute another `prompt::common::DIR_SEPARATOR`

Comment: I just used (on windows with visual studio command prompt): 
dumpbin /exports and 
dumbin /symbols 
and 
nm 
tools to see the library information and DIR_SEPARATOR is not there.

Comment: @jplc -open *lib* file simply in notepad. and search in notepad for *__imp_?DIR_SEPARATOR@common@@3DB* but your obvivous error in *prompt::common::DIR_SEPARATOR* - you use here absolute another symbol. you must use *common::DIR_SEPARATOR* - so remove *prompt::*

Comment: @RbMm there's no  __imp_?DIR_SEPARATOR@common@@3DB symbol neither __imp_?DIR_SEPARATOR@common@prompt@@3DB. So, is extern keyword doing something?

Comment: simply upload your lib and show link for look. if you do correct - must be `__imp?DIR_SEPARATOR@common@@3DB` symbol here. the **prompt** of course must not be, if you not declare symbol in dll in promt namespace

Comment: for [example](https://www.sendspace.com/file/mm397n) i build dll which export symbol exactly as you declared. you can see `__imp?DIR_SEPARATOR@common@@3DB` here direct or say via *link /dump /exports libname* and i without any problem import this from *exe* (more exatly i put it no external *NT* namespace by error - so in my lib symbol `__imp?DIR_SEPARATOR@common@NT@@3DB`

Comment: I created this project as "DLL project". And I found out that when I change my project settings from DLL (dynamic) to LIB (static) I have no linking errors using the .lib static file generated. 
Why this happened if building DLL generates the LIB file automatically?
Why I need to change my project configuration type to static (LIB) explicitly to generate a different .lib file to get no errors?

Changes to Visual Studio project were:
project properties->Configuration properties->General->Configuration Type
from DLL to LIB
Sounds weird but it works for linking. 
Apologies I'm new on VS.